How to test equality in IAS Machine programming
I've got to write a program in IAS Machine assembly language that sums every item of an array, except the array[i] item.
Although, i've not yet found a way to test equality of two values to determine whether the item of the array is the one i won't sum in the iteration, as i can't just subtract one from another, as the only conditional operator tests for values >= 0, having no way of knowing if it's just zero.
I've created two variables, one to point to the item i will not sum in the iteration, and one 'j' variable.
021     00 00 00 00 05      # variable j
022     00 00 00 00 01      # constant 1
024     00 00 00 00 30      # pointer array[i]

My plan was to compare the variable j with the position of array[i] to see if they are the same, then not adding it to the sum.
